# Rearrange sparse arrays by swapping rows and columns

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have large but sparse arrays and I want to rearrange them by swapping rows an columns. What is a good way to do this in `scipy.sparse`?

Some issues

- I don't think that permutation matrices are well suited for this task, as they like randomly change the sparsity structure. And a manipulation will always 'multiply' all columns or rows, even if there are only a few swaps necessary.
- What is the best sparse matrix representation in `scipy.sparse` for this task?
- Suggestions for implementation are very welcome.

I have tagged this with Matlab as well, since this question might find an answer that is not necessarily `scipy` specific.

Comment: I need this for a particular implementation. However, as a colleague pointed out to me, in general, one would not do permutations on a sparse matrix. A sparse matrix `A` is generally used as a linear map `y=Ax`, e.g. in iterative solvers. Thus this swapping is better realized by writing a wrapper around `A`, swapping the entries of the input vector x (this is column swapping in `A`) or the entries of `y` (this is row swapping).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSC format keeps a list of the row indices of all non-zero entries, CSR format keeps a list of the column indices of all non-zero entries. I think you can take advantage of that to swap things around as follows, and I think there shouldn't be any side-effects to it:

```
def swap_rows(mat, a, b) :
    mat_csc = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(mat)
    a_idx = np.where(mat_csc.indices == a)
    b_idx = np.where(mat_csc.indices == b)
    mat_csc.indices[a_idx] = b
    mat_csc.indices[b_idx] = a
    return mat_csc.asformat(mat.format)

def swap_cols(mat, a, b) :
    mat_csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(mat)
    a_idx = np.where(mat_csr.indices == a)
    b_idx = np.where(mat_csr.indices == b)
    mat_csr.indices[a_idx] = b
    mat_csr.indices[b_idx] = a
    return mat_csr.asformat(mat.format)
```

You could now do something like this:

```
>>> mat = np.zeros((5,5))
>>> mat[[1, 2, 3, 3], [0, 2, 2, 4]] = 1
>>> mat = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(mat)
>>> mat.todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> swap_rows(mat, 1, 3)
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
>>> swap_rows(mat, 1, 3).todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> swap_cols(mat, 0, 4)
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
>>> swap_cols(mat, 0, 4).todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I have used a LIL matrix to show how you could preserve the type of your output. In your application you probably want to already be in CSC or CSR format, and select whether to swap rows or columns first based on it, to minimize conversions.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, this seems to be what I was looking for. And it shows that I should get more familiar with the sparse formats.

Comment: @Jan You may want to test it a little more, I think the examples above work because all the non-zero entries are the same. I don't have time right now, but will look into it in more detail later. There is another array, `mat.indptr`, which may need some changing too. [The wikipedia article on the Yale sparse format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Yale_format) has all the information needed, in case you want to try it yourself!

Comment: I will test it and let you know... Thanks for the source.

Comment: Some of the sparse formats support fancy indexing like things too you could use. (I think)

Comment: @Jan It should work fine, sorry for the noise. After fooling around with the `indices` parameter you can run `.sort_indices()` to get it to a more standard form. But `indptr` will remain the same through those changes.

Comment: Based on this answer I have written a function `col_columns_atend` that shifts a set of columns of a sparse matrix to the right end. Feel free to check it out from [github](https://github.com/highlando/pystokes/blob/master/time_int_schemes.py). I have tested it in `utest.py` in the same repo.

Comment: @Jan If it works for you, then all is good. I think you could use a lot more numpy to get rid of the for loop, but it would probably both obfuscate the code, and depending on how much data you have and how many columns you move, not be too noticeable in performance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found using matrix operations to be the most efficient. Here's a function which will permute the rows and/or columns to a specified order. It can be modified to swap two specific rows/columns if you would like.

```py
from scipy import sparse

def permute_sparse_matrix(M, row_order=None, col_order=None):
    """
    Reorders the rows and/or columns in a scipy sparse matrix to the specified order.
    """
    if row_order is None and col_order is None:
        return M
    
    new_M = M
    if row_order is not None:
        I = sparse.eye(M.shape[0]).tocoo()
        I.row = I.row[row_order]
        new_M = I.dot(new_M)
    if col_order is not None:
        I = sparse.eye(M.shape[1]).tocoo()
        I.col = I.col[col_order]
        new_M = new_M.dot(I)
    return new_M
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you can just index the columns and rows the way you like:

```
Matrix = speye(10);
mycolumnorder = [1 2 3 4 5 6 10 9 8 7];
myroworder = [4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10];
Myorderedmatrix = Matrix(myroworder,mycolumnorder);
```

I think this preserves sparsity... Don't know about scipy though...