# "Densifying" very large sparse matrices by rearranging rows/columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a very large sparse matrix (240k*4.5k, ≤1% non-zero elements), which I would like to "densify" by rearranging its rows and columns in a way that the upper left region is enriched in non-zero elements as much as possible. (To make it more manageable and visually assessable.) I would prefer `scipy` and related tools to do this.

- A good suggestion was already made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155276/rearrange-sparse-arrays-by-swapping-rows-and-columns) for a solution to "manually" swap rows/columns of sparse matrices, but it does not cover the challenge of identifying which rows/columns to swap to get an optimal enrichment (dense block) in the upper left corner.
- Note that a simple sorting of rows/columns based on the number of non-zero elements does not solve the problem. (If I take *e.g.* the two rows with the most elements, there will not necessarily be any overlap between them in terms of where - *i.e.* in which columns - are the elements located.)
- I'm also curious about the optimal sparse matrix representation in `scipy.sparse` for this task.

Any suggestions or specific implementation ideas are welcome.

Comment: MATLAB has sparse matrix rearragement methods to improve linear algebra solutions. I'm not aware of any in the `scipy` code. But scan the sparse linalg docs to be sure. Also look for applied math papers. MATLAB uses `csc`, but probably does rearranging in compiled code.

Comment: `csr` and `csc` matrix row and column summation and indexing is done with matrix multiplication. So this reordering can probably be done in the same way.  I've answered some recent SO about this.

Comment: scikit learn has some compiled sparse utility code. Study its docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately my data has nothing to do with linear algebra, so `scipy.linalg` won't help much. (I don't want to transform the matrix in any other way, just rearrange it.) Also, the sparse tools in `scikit-learn` are concerned mostly with "sparse coding", a concept I'm not really familiar with, which I don't think will solve my problem.

Comment: Forget about sparse formats for now.  Work out how you want to reorder rows and columns using (sparse) dense arrays.  There indexing and counting is fast and simple.  Then you can worry about implementing it with sparse matrices.  Most likely the sparse version will involve a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with the solution below:
- First of all, based on the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix), the LiL (linked list) format seems to be ideal for this sort of operations. (However I never did any actual comparison!)
- I've used the functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15162737/6869965) to swap rows and columns.
- Following the [suggestion of elyase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791339/6869965), I defined a 200*200 'window' in the 'upper left' corner of the matrix and implemented a 'window score' which was simply equal to the number of non-zero elements inside the window.
- To identify the columns to swap, I checked which column contains the least non-zero elements inside the window, and which column contains the most non-zero elements outside the window. In case of a tie, the number of non-zero elements in the whole column was the tie-breaker (if this was tied as well, I've chosen randomly).
- The method for swapping rows was identical.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import operator

def swap_rows(mat, a, b):
    ''' See link in description'''

def swap_cols(mat, a, b) :
    ''' See link in description'''

def windowScore(lilmatrix,window):
    ''' Return no. of non-zero elements inside window. '''
    a=lilmatrix.nonzero()

    return sum([1 for i,j in list(zip(a[0],a[1])) if i<window and j<window])

def colsToSwap(lilmatrix,window):
    ''' Determine columns to be swapped.
    In: lil_matrix, window (to what col_no is it considered "left") 
    Out: (minColumnLeft,maxColumnRight) columns inside/outside of window w/ least/most NZ elements'''

    # Locate non-zero elements
    a=lilmatrix.nonzero()

    totalCols=lilmatrix.get_shape()[1]

    # Store no. of NZ elements for each column {in the window,in the whole table}, initialize with zeros
    colScoreWindow=np.zeros(totalCols)
    colScoreWhole=np.zeros(totalCols)

    ### Set colScoreWindow scores
    # Unique row indices
    rows_uniq={k for k in a[0] if k<window}
    for k in rows_uniq:
        # List of tuples w/ location of each NZ element in current row
        gen=((row,col) for row,col in list(zip(a[0],a[1])) if row==k)
        for row,col in gen:
           # Increment no. of NZ elements in current column in colScoreWindow
            colScoreWindow[col]+=1

    ### Set colScoreWhole scores
    # Unique row indices
    rows_uniq={k for k in a[0]}
    for k in rows_uniq:
        # List of tuples w/ location of each NZ element in current row
        gen=((row,col) for row,col in list(zip(a[0],a[1])) if row==k)
        for row,col in gen:
            # Increment no. of NZ elements in current column in colScoreWhole
            colScoreWhole[col]+=1


    # Column inside of window w/ least NZ elements
    minColumnLeft=sorted(list(zip(np.arange(totalCols),colScoreWindow,colScoreWhole,np.random.rand(totalCols)))[:window], key=operator.itemgetter(1,2,3))[0][0]
    # Column outside of window w/ most NZ elements
    maxColumnRight=sorted(list(zip(np.arange(totalCols),colScoreWindow,colScoreWhole,np.random.rand(totalCols)))[window:], key=operator.itemgetter(1,2,3))[-1][0]

    return (minColumnLeft,maxColumnRight)

def rowsToSwap(lilmatrix,window):
    ''' Same as colsToSwap, adjusted for rows.'''
```

After running a suitable number of iterations of `colsToSwap` and `rowsToSwap` and the actual swapping functions, the number of non-zero elements inside the window converges to a maximum. Note that the method is not optimized at all, and there is much room for improvement. For example, I suspect that reducing the number of sparse matrix type conversions and/or the `a=lilmatrix.nonzero()` call would significantly speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can already swap rows preserving sparsity so the missing part is the algorithm to sort the rows. So you need a function that gives you a "leftness" score. A heuristic that could work is the following:

1. first get a mask of the non-zero elements (you don't care about the actual values, only about its non-zeroness).
2. Estimate the density distribution of the non-zero values along the column axis:

   ```
   def density(row, window):
       padded = np.insert(row, 0, 0)
       cumsum = np.cumsum(padded) 
       return (cumsum[window:] - cumsum[:-window]) / window
   ```
3. Calculate the leftness score as the column with the maximum left-penalised density (looking from the right):

   ```
   def leftness_score(row):
       n = len(a)
       window = n / 10   # 10 is a tuneable hyper parameter
       smoothness = 1    # another parameter to play with
       d = density(row)
       penalization = np.exp(-smoothness * np.arange(n))
       return n - (penalization * d).argmax()
   ```

This algorithm gives higher score to rows having a high density of values as long as the max value of this density is not too far to the right. Some ideas to take it further: improve the density estimation, play with different penalization functions (instead of neg exp), fit the parameters to some synthethic data reflecting your expected sorting, etc.

Comment: Thank you, these are really useful suggestions. However, they still need to be improved on a few points. First of all, it's not clear to me why you insert a 0 in front of the row in `density`. (I see it changes the result, but why is it important?) It also raises a `ValueError operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4508,) (4059,)` on the return statement of `leftness_score`. Strangely enough, if I change the definition of `padded` to `padded = row`, the error remains: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4508,) (4058,)`

Comment: Also, there are two typos: `d = density(row)` misses an argument, correctly: `d = density(row,window)`. And in `n = len(a)`, `a` is not defined, should it be `n = len(row)`?

Comment: Oops, I misread 4508 and 4058 and thought they were the same. In the meantime, I figured out the reason of the `ValueError`: the vector returned by `density` is `window` values shorter than `row`. Will try to work on a solution, but feel free to suggest any ideas.

Comment: Oh I should have warned that the code is untested, it is just some buggy code I wrote quickly to better illustrate the general idea of the algorithm (as they say a line of code is better than 1000 words). Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: No worries, it was thought-provoking, and that's the most important. I'll post my final solution once I'm ready.